# How to read data from Excel sheet in Linux using Shell Script?

Tags: linux, excel, bash, shell, unix

EveryOne,
 I am new in Linux & very much interested to write shell scripts. This time I am making a excel sheet. In that excel sheet there will be S.No. in 1st column & Domain names in second column. There are 100 of domains in my excel sheet. So, I do not want to manually copy every domain & paste them into browser to check all. I simply want to write a shell script which can open all the domains into browser by running the single shell script.
 Please help me out. I will be very grateful to you.

Thanks & Regards-
Reetesh Chauhan

Comment: Using a less obnoxious file format would simplify things a lot.

Comment: Shell scripts really like to work on lines of text so step 1 should be to convert to a different format, e.g. CSV

Answer (score 12):

`xls2csv` will get your xls file into a CSV format.

Pipe that to `sed` to remove the double-quotes.

Use `while` to iterate over each line.

`echo` each line (`l`) to `awk` to get the second (`$2`) column into the `$d` (for domain) variable.

Then send that to browser. You can replace `lynx` with your favorite browser. A GUI browser will work as easily as a TUI one.

```
xls2csv domains.xls | sed -e's/"//g' | while read l; do d=`echo "$l" | awk  '{print $2}'`; lynx "$d"; done
```

Comment: Note that `xls2csv` will only work with Office 97-2003 format. If you have LibreOffice, you can run `libreoffice --headless --convert-to xls /path/to/source.xlsx` to convert it.

Comment: You can use `xlsx2csv` for Excel 2007 and later.

Answer (score 3):

you can use samples: [help1](http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/convert-csv-to-xls-603977.html)
[help2](http://adambuchanan.me/post/66916185081/keyword-research-in-an-excel-spreadsheet)
[help3](http://bd.summit.net/articles/2013/10/09/create-excel-file-using-bash-script/#gsc.tab=0)

you can use `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("test.xls"); 
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
open(FH,"<file") or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
my ($x,$y) = (0,0);
while (<FH>){ 
 chomp;
 @list = split /\s+/,$_;
 foreach my $c (@list){
    $worksheet->write($x, $y++, $c);     
 }
 $x++;$y=0;
}
close(FH);
$workbook->close();
```

and `python` as well:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# Tool to convert CSV files (with configurable delimiter and text wrap
# character) to Excel spreadsheets.
import string
import sys
import getopt
import re
import os
import os.path
import csv
from pyExcelerator import *

def usage():
  """ Display the usage """
  print "Usage:" + sys.argv[0] + " [OPTIONS] csvfile"
  print "OPTIONS:"
  print "--title|-t: If set, the first line is the title line"
  print "--lines|-l n: Split output into files of n lines or less each"
  print "--sep|-s c [def:,] : The character to use for field delimiter"
  print "--output|o : output file name/pattern"
  print "--help|h : print this information"
  sys.exit(2)

def openExcelSheet(outputFileName):
  """ Opens a reference to an Excel WorkBook and Worksheet objects """
  workbook = Workbook()
  worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")
  return workbook, worksheet

def writeExcelHeader(worksheet, titleCols):
  """ Write the header line into the worksheet """
  cno = 0
  for titleCol in titleCols:
    worksheet.write(0, cno, titleCol)
    cno = cno + 1

def writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, columns):
  """ Write a non-header row into the worksheet """
  cno = 0
  for column in columns:
    worksheet.write(lno, cno, column)
    cno = cno + 1

def closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName):
  """ Saves the in-memory WorkBook object into the specified file """
  workbook.save(outputFileName)

def getDefaultOutputFileName(inputFileName):
  """ Returns the name of the default output file based on the value
      of the input file. The default output file is always created in
      the current working directory. This can be overriden using the
      -o or --output option to explicitly specify an output file """
  baseName = os.path.basename(inputFileName)
  rootName = os.path.splitext(baseName)[0]
  return string.join([rootName, "xls"], '.')

def renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno):
  """ Renames the output file name by appending the current file number
      to it """
  dirName, baseName = os.path.split(outputFileName)
  rootName, extName = os.path.splitext(baseName)
  backupFileBaseName = string.join([string.join([rootName, str(fno)], '-'), extName], '')
  backupFileName = os.path.join(dirName, backupFileBaseName)
  try:
    os.rename(outputFileName, backupFileName)
  except OSError:
    print "Error renaming output file:", outputFileName, "to", backupFileName, "...aborting"
    sys.exit(-1)

def validateOpts(opts):
  """ Returns option values specified, or the default if none """
  titlePresent = False
  linesPerFile = -1
  outputFileName = ""
  sepChar = ","
  for option, argval in opts:
    if (option in ("-t", "--title")):
      titlePresent = True
    if (option in ("-l", "--lines")):
      linesPerFile = int(argval)
    if (option in ("-s", "--sep")):
      sepChar = argval
    if (option in ("-o", "--output")):
      outputFileName = argval
    if (option in ("-h", "--help")):
      usage()
  return titlePresent, linesPerFile, sepChar, outputFileName

def main():
  """ This is how we are called """
  try:
    opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "tl:s:o:h", ["title", "lines=", "sep=", "output=", "help"])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
  if (len(args) != 1):
    usage()
  inputFileName = args[0]
  try:
    inputFile = open(inputFileName, 'r')
  except IOError:
    print "File not found:", inputFileName, "...aborting"
    sys.exit(-1)
  titlePresent, linesPerFile, sepChar, outputFileName = validateOpts(opts)
  if (outputFileName == ""):
    outputFileName = getDefaultOutputFileName(inputFileName)
  workbook, worksheet = openExcelSheet(outputFileName)
  fno = 0
  lno = 0
  titleCols = []
  reader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=sepChar)
  for line in reader:
    if (lno == 0 and titlePresent):
      if (len(titleCols) == 0):
        titleCols = line
      writeExcelHeader(worksheet, titleCols)
    else:
      writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, line)
    lno = lno + 1
    if (linesPerFile != -1 and lno >= linesPerFile):
      closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName)
      renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno)
      fno = fno + 1
      lno = 0
      workbook, worksheet = openExcelSheet(outputFileName)
  inputFile.close()
  closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName)
  if (fno > 0):
    renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Isn't your answer doing opposite of what OP wanted? It is writing instead of reading it. Thanks for pyExcelerator suggestion.