# I am trying to open a excel file in ubuntu, but its displaying garbage characters

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, xlsx

I am trying to read an xlsx file in ubuntu, but all it shows is garbage characters.
I am running the ubuntu instance in a docker, so i have no GUI. I am sending the excel file from windows to ubuntu and there i am trying to check if it has a particular text in it. How can I achieve this using terminal?

[image]

Comment: xlsx is just a zipped xml. You may be able to use `zip` and then `grep`, but this is just a guess.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to use something better than `cat`. [Why using cat on binary files messed up the terminal and how?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how)

Comment: What are problem are you trying to solve? Do you need just some bits out of the excel file? Or do you want to edit it?

Comment: @Tobi I am trying to check if the excel has a particular value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from Excel sheet in Linux using Shell Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686354/how-to-read-data-from-excel-sheet-in-linux-using-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install xlsx2csv in the container and then use it to make a csv

csv can be read with any editor, bash tools etc

```
apt-get install xlsx2csv
xlsx2csv book.xlsx > convert.csv
```

Comment: What happens if there are multiple tabs in xlsx?